# OpenSSL SSL_library_init() returns LeaveCriticalSection

Tags: c++, windows, dll, openssl

I am developing C++ project in Visual Studio 2012.

And my linker command line is below:

```
/OUT:"..\bin\Debug\x86\BANANA.C.Helper.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"..\bin\Debug\x86\BANANA.C.Helper.pdb"
/DYNAMICBASE "zlibstat.lib" "iphlpapi.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
"comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib"
"odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"..\bin\Debug\x86\BANANA.C.Helper.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86
/INCREMENTAL /PGD:"..\bin\Debug\x86\BANANA.C.Helper.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /NOLOGO
/ManifestFile:"Debug\BANANA.C.Helper.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT
/LIBPATH:"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin" /LIBPATH:"D:\#Library\C++\boost_1_55_0-msvc-11.0-32\lib32-msvc-11.0"
/TLBID:1
```

When I call `SSL_library_init`, I get `C_test.exe has triggered a breakpoint` error.

[image]

But in the same source in another project, it just works fine.

I reckon there is something to do with project options, but I cannot find any information about `SSL_library_init() returns LeaveCriticalSection`.

Does anyone have any idea?

**EDIT**

The error source is in mlock.c.

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
    int locknum
    )
{
    /*
     * leave the critical section.
     */
    LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
} ---> here
```

The error code is below:

[image]

Comment: Press "Break" and show us the stack.

Comment: @selalerer There is no stack to trace. I attached image of error point.

Comment: When you break the process, it stops at a certain point in the execution of the program. The debugger is showing you where that is and is also showing you, in another window, the call stack. This window may not be displayed at the moment. If so, look for it in the menus (either under "debug" or under "view" menus).

Comment: Did you initialize your critical sections? This sort of initialization is tricky in a Windows DLL because of the restrictions on `DLLmain`.